# getting this error: PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, php

After installation I am getting this error:

```
    PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'civicrm_handler_field_custom_file-class' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {registry} (name, type, filename, module, weight) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4); 
Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => civicrm_handler_field_custom_file [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => class [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/modules/views/civicrm/civicrm_handler_field_custom_file.inc [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => civicrm [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0 ) in _registry_parse_file() (line 179 of /xxxx/drupal70/includes/registry.inc).
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by truncating all the caching tables using mysql query.
I followed following steps:

```
1. Connect Sql server 
2. Truncate the all the cache tables and they are as follows:
truncate cache;
truncate cache_admin_menu;
truncate cache_block;
truncate cache_bootstrap;
truncate cache_field;
truncate cache_filter;
truncate cache_form;
truncate cache_image;
truncate cache_libraries;
truncate cache_media_xml;
truncate cache_menu;
truncate cache_page;
truncate cache_path;
truncate cache_token;
truncate cache_views;
truncate cache_views_data;
```

By doing this above steps I can able to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems like you have two duplicate entries for `civicrm_handler_filter_custom_file-class` in registry table.

To fix, try deleting one of them, i.e, in `registry` table of drupal database

- Search for `civicrm_handler_filter_custom_file-class` in `name` column.
- Check if there are two entries found.
- If yes, delete or rename one of them to see if it fixes the issue.